# Plot 3D histogram using bar3

Tags: matlab, visualization, histogram

I'm currently trying to plot the output of hist3 using bar3. This is a simple example:

```
vec_x = [1 2 4 5 7 8 9 3 8 7 2]';
vec_y = [1 3 9 5 7 8 1 3 2 9 2]';
vec_bin_edges = 0:9;
hist3([vec_x vec_y], 'Edges', {vec_bin_edges, vec_bin_edges});
mat_joint = hist3([vec_x vec_y], 'Edges', {vec_bin_edges, vec_bin_edges});
figure
bar3(mat_joint, 1);
axis tight
```

In order to demonstrate my issue, I made two pics of both figures:

This one is the output of `hist3([vec_x vec_y], 'Edges', {vec_bin_edges, vec_bin_edges});`

[image]

This one is the output of `bar3(mat_joint, 1);`
[image]

As you can see, the `bar3` function does not really "bin" the data values as `hist3` does, so the bars are shifted slightly in their positions. My question is now, whether it's possible to make the `bar3` plot look exactly like the `hist3` plot. My motivation to do so is, that I need to modify the `mat_joint` matrix and plot it again, which is not possible using `hist3`.

EDIT: The different colors are not important, it's just about the bin positions

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured it out:

```
set(gca, 'xtick', [1.5:1:10.5]);
set(gca, 'ytick', [1.5:1:10.5]);
vec_bin_labels = 1:10;
vec_string_bin_labels = reshape(cellstr(num2str(vec_bin_labels(:))), size(vec_bin_labels));
set(gca, 'xticklabel', vec_string_bin_labels);
set(gca, 'yticklabel', vec_string_bin_labels);
```